The ttkbootstrap style is not working. How can I fix it?
The ttkbootstrap style is not working.
The window looks like this.

The full code is here.
This is my code:
a.py:
from tkinter import filedialog
import ttkbootstrap as ttk
from ttkbootstrap.constants import *
from b import *

root = ttk.Window()

b1 = ttk.Button(root, text="Button 1", bootstyle=SUCCESS, command=test)
b1.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5, pady=10)

b2 = ttk.Button(root, text="Button 2", bootstyle=(INFO, OUTLINE))
b2.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5, pady=10)

root.mainloop()

b.py:
import ttkbootstrap as ttk
from ttkbootstrap.constants import *

def test():
    root = ttk.Window()

    b1 = ttk.Button(root, text="Button 1", bootstyle=SUCCESS)
    b1.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5, pady=10)

    root.mainloop()

When I call test() function in a.py, the window created by b.py looks strange.
It's still the tkinter style.
How can I fix it? I don't like the tkinter style.


When I call test() function in a.py, the window created by b.py looks
strange. It's still the tkinter style.
How can I fix it? I don't like the tkinter style.

The problem can be fixed.
On b.py.
Change this:
root = ttk.Window()

to:
root = ttk.Toplevel()

Use one mainloop() for entire modules.
Snippet:
import ttkbootstrap as ttk
from ttkbootstrap.constants import *

def test():
    root = ttk.Toplevel()

    b1 = ttk.Button(root, text="Button 3", bootstyle=SUCCESS)
    b1.pack(side=LEFT, padx=55, pady=10)

    #root.mainloop()

Screenshot for a.py:

Screenshot for b.py:

